# How do accounts not yet created get loaded by the runtime with Cross Program Invocation?

Tags: account, program, cpi

In the code reproduced below from this [link](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/create-account/native/tests/test.ts#L38) we have client code creating and sending instruction to create a new account:

```
describe("Create a system account", async () => {

    const connection = new Connection(`http://localhost:8899`, 'confirmed');
    const payer = createKeypairFromFile(require('os').homedir() + '/.config/solana/id.json');
    const program = createKeypairFromFile('./program/target/so/program-keypair.json');
  
    it("Create the account", async () => {

        const newKeypair = Keypair.generate();

        let ix = new TransactionInstruction({
            keys: [
                {pubkey: payer.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},
                {pubkey: newKeypair.publicKey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true},
                {pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false}
            ],
            programId: program.publicKey,
            data: Buffer.alloc(0),
        });

        await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            connection, 
            new Transaction().add(ix),
            [payer, newKeypair]
        );
    });
  });
```

here the new account to be created is represented by the public key `newKeypair.publicKey`.

The Solana program that process the instruction, which can be found via this [link](https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/basics/create-account/native/program/src/lib.rs) looks thus:

```
fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    _instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {

    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let payer = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let new_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let system_program = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    
    msg!("Program invoked. Creating a system account...");
    msg!("  New public key will be: {}", &new_account.key.to_string());
    
    invoke(
        &system_instruction::create_account(
            &payer.key,             // From pubkey
            &new_account.key,       // To pubkey
            1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,   // Lamports (1 SOL)
            0,                      // Space
            &system_program::ID,    // Owner
        ),
        &[
            payer.clone(), new_account.clone(), system_program.clone()  // Accounts involved
        ]
    )?;

    msg!("Account created succesfully.");
    Ok(())
}
```

I understand when calling Solana programs we pass in, the accounts that the run time should retrieve that will be needed for executing the instructions. In the case above, where we are including an account that does not exist (the instruction we are passing in, is actually for it to be created) how then does the Solana program load a non-existing account?

Specifically this line:

```
let new_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
```

Why does not not error since the program does not exist until the `&system_instruction::create_account` call is invoked?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are asking how `newKeypair` is used to create an account where you are referring to `newKeypair` as a `non-existing account`. Here you got it wrong, newKeypair is not an account it is just a public and secret key pair that is generated randomly and the instruction creates a new account whose owner(Assigned Program ID) is System Program and newKeypair's public key is used to set the newly created account's public key. Same instruction is also available in Solana Web3 SDK you can check [this](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/fb6b079b2c9c39b5118068a52b9a2ebeec092989/src/programs/system.ts#L18).

Comment: I was actually referring to `new_account` in the Solana program side. If the account does not exist, how come the run time was able to find and load it. I now have the answer to this. And that is, the Solana runtime can load any account (since technically the account is basically a public key) the only difference is that, account can either have been initialised or not. An account that has not being initialised (or said in another way, an account that has not being created yet) will have its lamport set to 0